# Printing lists in python gives unwanted output

Tags: python

I am having a problem printing list in Python.

I am gathering elements of a dictionary into a list and then trying to print the list. But the list that is printed includes the enclosing brackets '[]'.

Here is my code and the result:

```
my_secrets_list = []
aws_secret = secrets_client.create_secret(Name=secret_name,Description=secret_description,KmsKeyId=kms_key_id,SecretString=key_info,Tags=[{'Key': 'Name','Value': user_name}])
secret_name = aws_secret['Name']
my_secrets_list.append(secret_name)
print("My secrets", my_secrets_list)
```

This is an [aws_secret](http://secret_name%20=%20aws_secret['Name'])

And this is the output:

```
My secrets ['aws-user10-jf-python-dev-keys']
```

I would like to print the list called my_secrets_list without the enclosing brackets or quotes.

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't print the list, print the elements inside the list.

Comment: Random tip: stick to single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes to give your code a more uniform stylistic feel. You'll also save yourself time in the long run as you won't have to keep correcting syntax errors!

Comment: That's a good tip! Thanks! I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `str.join` method to join your list of strings into a nicely printable comma-separated list.

I.e.

```
my_secrets_list = []
aws_secret = secrets_client.create_secret(Name=secret_name,Description=secret_description,KmsKeyId=kms_key_id,SecretString=key_info,Tags=[{'Key': 'Name','Value': user_name}])
secret_name = aws_secret['Name']
my_secrets_list.append(secret_name)
print("My secrets", ', '.join(my_secrets_list))
```

I can't test this, but I can assure that the basic principle of what is being done here works fine:

```
l = ['hello', 'jim', 'bob']
print('My list:', ', '.join(l))
#My list: hello, jim, bob
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace

```
print("My secrets", my_secrets_list)
```

with

```
print("My secrets", my_secrets_list[0])
```

Comment: This works fine when `my_secrets_list` only contains one string, but if it contains multiple elements, the other elements obviously won't be displayed.